# ios tableview inside a container not clickable

Tags: ios, uitableview

I put a tableview inside a container and the last visible row of the tableview is not clickable.

`_purchaseInvoiceListTable` - tableViewController

```
[_purchaseInvoiceListTable setDataSource:_purchaseDataSource];
[_purchaseInvoiceListTable.view setFrame:_purchaseInvoiceListTableContainer.bounds];
[_purchaseInvoiceListTableContainer addSubview:[_purchaseInvoiceListTable view]];
[_purchaseInvoiceListTable willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:_purchaseInvoiceListTable];
[_purchaseInvoiceListTable didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Why?

Comment: Can you check the frame of your uiviewcontroller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have clipsToBounds set on the container ?

```
_purchaseInvoiceListTableContainer.clipsToBounds = YES;
```